# How to transform a 'string' into $VariableName Not for Debugging

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, pdo

I'm trying to make an array to insert the data of that array in a table(2) of the database, let me introduce you to the problem.

The thing is I want this array (since now called `$myArray`) be constructed from another for the mix of another two or three arrays, which are `$arBase`, `$arPost` and `$dPost`.

```
$arBase = array(
            'title',
            'Prelude',
            'Text',
            'nombr1',
            'nombr2',
            'nombr3',
            'nombr4',
            'regin',
            'ctgry',
            'RutIm'
                );

 $arPost = array(
    $_POST['Titulo2'],
    $_POST['Preludio2'],
    $_POST['Comentario2'],
    $_POST['NOMBR1(2)'],
    $_POST['NOMBR2(2)'],
    $_POST['NOMBR3(2)'],
    $_POST['NOMBR4(2)'],
    $_POST['regin(2)'],
    $_POST['ctgry2'],
    $_POST['RutIm']
                );

    $smr = $smt->fetch(); //fetch of table(1) different to the query of table(2) showed ahead                   

 $dPost = array(
        $smr['Title'],
        $smr['Prelude'],
        $smr['Text'],
        $smr['NOMBR1'],
        $smr['NOMBR2'],
        $smr['NOMBR3'],
        $smr['NOMBR4'],
        $smr['REGIN'],
        $smr['CTGRY'],
        $smr['RutIm']
                );

 $miArray = array();


 echo '<br /><br />ArBase: ';
 var_dump($arBase);
 echo '<br /><br />ArPost: ';
 var_dump($arPost);
 echo '<br /><br />dPost: ';
 var_dump($dPost);
```

This is actually going to print this:

```
ArBase: array(10) { 
[0]=> string(5) "title" 
[1]=> string(7) "Prelude" 
[2]=> string(4) "Text" 
[3]=> string(6) "nombr1" 
[4]=> string(6) "nombr2" 
[5]=> string(6) "nombr3" 
[6]=> string(6) "nombr4" 
[7]=> string(5) "regin" 
[8]=> string(5) "ctgry" 
[9]=> string(5) "RutIm" }

ArPost: array(10) { 
[0]=> string(15) "llegar y Llevar" // This was the only filled in the $_POST[''] in the form
[1]=> string(0) "" 
[2]=> string(0) "" 
[3]=> string(0) "" 
[4]=> string(0) "" 
[5]=> string(0) "" 
[6]=> string(0) "" 
[7]=> string(0) "" 
[8]=> string(0) "" 
[9]=> NULL }

dPost: array(10) { // this ones come from another table(1) in the database
[0]=> string(20) "Vas A VIVIV CALABERA" 
[1]=> string(85) "tener con vos me miro fijo y volvi" 
[2]=> string(37) "ella me dijo 4 " 
[3]=> string(3) "The" 
[4]=> string(7) "Name" 
[5]=> string(6) "of" 
[6]=> string(8) "Somebody" 
[7]=> string(13) "Metropoli" 
[8]=> string(5) "Ctgry" 
[9]=> string(23) "images/padlock2.gif.jpg" }
```

The idea is simple, I want to make `$myArray` be build selectively, this means that, if data was sent through `$_POST`, then the value of that `$_POST` will be the data of that specific value in the `$myArray`, but, if this was not set (and because of that, is `""` or have just `" "`) then it make a query in the table(1) and add the specific content of that field enter in the corresponding value of `$myArray`.

Please have in mind for the future than table(1) and table(2) are *almost* clones but are **not** the same table.

Until here, all is fine, but then I encountered a problem:

```
//This is the only table category difference between the two tables
$date =  $smr['Date']; //the fetch for the Date value of the table(1)
        $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date)); //Here is converted in Timestamp to be inserted on table(2)

 // Say hi to table(2)
 $qls = "INSERT INTO `u739462586_dtren`.`chcknw` 
 (Title, Prelude, Text, Time, `NOMBR1`, `NOMBR2`, `NOMBR3`, `NOMBR4`, `REGIN`, `CTGRY`, `RutIm`) 
 VALUES (:Title, :Prelude, :Text, :Time, :NOMBR1, :NOMBR2, :NOMBR3, :NOMBR4, :REGIN, :CTGRY, :RutIm)";

 $stmt = $con->prepare($qls);
 $stmt->bindParam(':Title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':Prelude', $Prelude, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':Text', $Text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':Time', $timestamp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':NOMBR1', $nombr1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':NOMBR2', $nombr2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':NOMBR3', $nombr3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':NOMBR4', $nombr4, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':REGIN', $regin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':CTGRY', $ctgry, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':RutIm', $RutIm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $rslt = $stmt->execute();
```

The variables used to bind inside the second table(2) have just the same names than the strings inside the `$arBase` variable, because I'm trying to make something like:

```
// of course this code is not gonna work, but is usefull because 'ilustrate' what i'm trying to do 
foreach ($myArray[]) {
        if (isset($arPost[]) && $arPost[] != "") {
                $miArray[] = '$'.$arBase[] => $arPost[]; //a bad attempt to transform the string content of $arBase in a variable name
            } else {
                $miArray[] = '$'.$arBase[] => $dPost[];
            }
        }
```

I want make something like `($myArray as $arBase => $arPost/$dPost)`. Of course this is a bad attempt of pseudocode, but it shows the idea, `$arBase's` 'strings' converted in `$VariablesNames` so, that way they can been assigned with the `$arPost` content or the `$dPost`content depending of `if (isset($arPost[]) && $arPost[] != "")` or not.

Taking in consideration the examples just before, after all the process `var_dump($myArray);` must return something like this:

```
$myArray: array(10) { 
    $title => string(5) "llegar y Llevar"
    $Prelude => string(7) "tener con vos me miro fijo y volvi"
    $Text => string(4) "ella me dijo 4 "
    $nombr1 => string(6) "The" 
    $nombr2 => string(6) "Name" 
    $nombr3 => string(6) "of"  
    $nombr4 => string(6) "Somebody" 
    $regin => string(5) "Metropoli" 
    $ctgry => string(5) "Ctgry" 
    $RutIm => string(5) "images/padlock2.gif.jpg" }
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Please feel free to ask or suggest modifications to the question itself, or to know more about the problem, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are overcomplicating things: You don't need to read the original values to re-insert everything again.

Instead, you should build a query dynamically, adding just the keys / values that you need to change. And as you are just sending strings and the type does not seem that important, you can send an array with values to the `execute()` method instead of binding the individual variables.

As far as I can see, you also need an sql `UPDATE` statement instead of an `INSERT` unless you remove the existing row first, which would make things even more unnecessary complicated. To accomplish that, you would have to add the ID to the post.

The result would look something like:

```
// add the first variable that you always need to set or only add a comma in the loop
// if the added value is not the first. See note at the bottom
$qls = "UPDATE `u739462586_dtren`.`chcknw` SET id=id";
$values = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
  // make sure you only add existing keys, perhaps you have a list
  // available already? Also only add non-empty values
  if (in_array($key, $existing_keys) && !empty($value))
  {
    $qls .= ", `{$key}` = :{$key}";
    $values[":{$key}"] = $value;
  }
}
// add a WHERE condition to update the right record
$qls .= " WHERE id=:id";
// You should send the correct ID with the post
$values[":id"] = $_POST['id'];
$stmt = $con->prepare($qls);
$rslt = $stmt->execute($values);
```

**Note:** I did a bit of an ugly hack to accommodate for the commas when building the query, you could also build an array of strings and implode that but that's an easy change to make yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i kinda understand it & it seems like a good aproach the change to the update aproach but just have a question, on my example with my arrays, what will be the $existing_keys?, or it be another thing? i'm not an expert on Php must say
Also i edit a little bit the question to be even more detailed, please take a look at it and thanks for the help.